Implement x-ray tracing in lambda function (Python)
I'm trying to implement X-Ray tracing for my chat application. Currently, my service map shows only Client -> API Gateway -> Lambda. I want to visualize the interactions between Lambda and external services like OpenAI and RDS. for ex- Client -> API Gateway -> Lambda-->OpenAIAPICall
When I attempt to use the X-Ray SDK to capture subsegments for these interactions, I encounter the following errors:
[WARNING]       2024-10-23T09:08:20.714Z        1fbe91bb-cc39-4004-bd81-889a081e59c8    Subsegment OpenAIAPICall discarded due to Lambda worker still initializing

this is the sample code where i am trying to trace for OpenAI:-
from aws_xray_sdk.core import xray_recorder
from aws_xray_sdk.core import patch_all

patch_all()

@xray_recorder.capture('OpenAIAPICall')
def call_openai_api():
    # Your OpenAI API call logic here

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    # Your main Lambda function logic
    call_openai_api()
    # Rest of your code

Note i am using these services- Lambda, ApiGateway, CloudFormation.
Could someone please assist me with this issue? Any help would be greatly appreciated.
Thanks in Advance`
Here i am expecting the OpenAI call after the lambda function:-
Same here after the lambda, OpenAI or any call which i want should be traced
